# Perl: Special array @_ is not really an alias?

Tags: perl

The special array, `@_` , where all the arguments passed to a function are present, is actually an alias to the arguments passed. Hence, any change we make directly to this special array `@_` will reflect in the main as well. This is clear.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

$\="\n";

sub func {
        print \@_;
        $_++ for(@_);
}

my @arr=(2..4);
print \@arr;
func(@arr);
print "@arr";
```

For the above program, I expected the reference of `@arr` and `@_` to point to the same location since it is an alias. But it is not so.

On running the above:

```
ARRAY(0x1b644d0)
ARRAY(0x1b644e0)
3 4 5
```

If they are pointing to 2 different locations, how the changes done in `@_` is reflecting in `@arr`?

Am I seeing something wrong? Please advice.

Comment: `@_` is not an alias to anything. That's not what the documentation says. The individual *elements* of `@_` are aliases.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This might answer you question:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

$\="\n";

sub func {
        print \@_;
        $_++ for(@_);
        print \$_ for @_; 
}

my @arr=(2..4);
print \@arr;
func(@arr);
print "@arr";
print \$_ for @arr;
```

**Output**

```
ARRAY(0x17fcba0)
ARRAY(0x1824288)
SCALAR(0x17fcc48)
SCALAR(0x18196f8)
SCALAR(0x1819710)
3 4 5
SCALAR(0x17fcc48)
SCALAR(0x18196f8)
SCALAR(0x1819710)
```

As you see, individual arguments have the same address but the container is not the same. If you push an item to `@_` in `func` the `@arr` will not change (so you can do `shift` in `funct`). So, each argument is an alias and array elements are passed as individual items. `@_` contains all items passed into the subroutine. If you want to modify an array argument you need to pass it by reference.

Answer (score 11):

`@_` isn't aliased; its elements are.

Remember that

```
func(@arr);
```

is the same as

```
func($arr[0], $arr[1], ...);
```

because the only thing that can be passed to a sub is a list of scalars, and an array evaluates to a list of its elements in list context.

So that means

```
func(@arr);
```

is basically the same as

```
local @_;
alias $_[0] = $arr[0];
alias $_[1] = $arr[1];
...
&func;
```

Changing the elements of `@_` will change elements of `@arr`, but adding and removing elements of `@_` won't change `@arr` since they are different arrays.

```
>perl -E"@a=(4..6); sub { $_[0] = '!';        say @_; }->(@a); say @a;"
!56
!56

>perl -E"@a=(4..6); sub { splice(@_,0,1,'!'); say @_; }->(@a); say @a;"
!56
456
```